# Return wrong date in moment js with full format "DD-MM-YYYYTHH:mm:SSZ"?

Tags: momentjs

I'm using momentjs to convert String to date in with full value of date and time and the result  always increases about 12 hours. just like the picture below.
[image]

So how come does it go like this and how I can do to solve the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Please include the code as text in your question instead of pictures.

Answer (score 2):

"Z" at the end indicates that the date is provided with UTC-0 zone. momentjs internally shifts the timezone to suit your own. You should omit it if you want to reformat provided datetime string.